# z be a complex number such that $\overline {z+2-i}$ = $2z-2i$. What is $|x|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

z be a complex number such that $\overline {z+2-i}$ = $2z-2i$. What is $|x|^2$

I am new to complex numbers and not quite understanding it. What would be the process and the guideline to solve this. Not asking to solve this completely but pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What is $|z|^2$ perhaps?

Comment: Either way, I would write $z$ as $z = x + yi$ and see what you can deduce about the values of $x$ and $y$

Comment: @SimonS why $z = x + yi$, i have seen some examples of this but why that?

Comment: Every complex number $z$ can be written uniquely as the sum of its real part, $x$, and of its imaginary part, $yi$. In particular if you have two complex numbers equal to each other

$$a + bi = c + di$$

then the equality holds if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d$. Use that idea for your problem by finding the real and imaginary parts of both sides of your equation.

Comment: @SimonS would i focus on both sides of the equation or just the one?

Comment: Both. You have two unknowns, $x$ and $y$, and need two equations. You will only deduce two equations by writing down both sides of your expression in terms of those variables.

Comment: @SimonS Can you explain to me what the line above $z+2-i$ is suppose to mean? Why doesn't $2z-2i$ have that

Comment: The bar is one notation for complex conjugate. $\overline{a+bi} = a - bi$. Some books use a different notation; for example, $(a+bi)^* = a-bi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $\overline{z+2-i}=\overline{z}+2+i =2z-2i$ and this rewrites to $\overline{z}=2z-2-3i$ ; now if we conjugate the last identity we get $z=2\overline{z}-2+3i$. Now we insert what we got above for $\overline{z}$ and we have

$$z=4z-4-6i-2+3i$$

And this gives solving for $z$

$$z=2+i$$

And from that we can compute either $|z|^2$ or $|x|^2$

Comment: When you wrote now we insert what we got above for z, what do you insert?

Comment: I replace $\overline{z}$ by $2z-2-3i$